# PyQt: how to terminate reusable QThread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, qthread

The majority of guides on QThread seem to focus on deleting the QThread after its QObject finishes. I would like to preserve QThread and QObject and reuse them when I need them again. This also means that I need to be more careful when managing their lifecycle because the Qt-python binding and their memory management can easily lead to some unexpected behaviour.

I am looking for the best practice to bind the lifecycle of the QThread and QObject to the GUI (QMainWindow, QFRame, etc...) which should perform proper clean-up during its destruction. I have prepared a minimal working example but maybe the community can point out its flaws and improve on it.

```
import sys
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import time

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("MyWindow")
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose) # this is OK
        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start thread")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        
        self.worker = MyObject()
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        # self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater) # for singleshot task
        # self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater) # for singleshot task

        # self.thread.start() # for singleshot task
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
        
    def __del__(self):
        print("MyWindow __del__ entered")
        self.thread.quit()
        print("MyWindow __del__ quit issued, waiting on thread")
        self.thread.wait()
        print("MyWindow __del__ thread returned")
        self.worker.deleteLater()
        self.thread.deleteLater()
        print("MyWindow __del__ quit")
        
    # def closeEvent(self, qCloseEvent):
    #     qCloseEvent.accept() # Also leads to crashes
    
class MyObject(QtCore.QObject):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    def run(self):
        print("MyObject run entered")
        time.sleep(1)
        self.finished.emit()
        print("MyObject run quit")

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    
    def run(self):
        print("MyThread run entered")
        self.exec()
        print("MyThread run quit")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainGui = MyWindow()
    mainGui.show()
    # app.aboutToQuit.connect(app.deleteLater) # Causes crashes
    app.exec()
```

This code produces the following result:

```
In [1]: runfile(...)
MyObject run entered
MyObject run quit
MyThread run entered
MyThread run quit
MyObject run entered
MyWindow __del__ entered
MyWindow __del__ quit issued, waiting on thread
MyWindow __del__ thread returned
MyWindow __del__ quit
MyObject run quit
MyThread run entered

In [2]: runfile(...)
MyThread run quit
```

This indicates that the thread was not deleted properly. Also, it surprised me that the `__del__` function is not blocked on calling `thread.wait()`, so the thread survives the QWidget. But at least it does not crash after multiple calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to re-use the thread, there's no point in doing any explicit clean-up, since Python/Qt will handle that automatically when the program exits. What you should instead do is add some kind of `stop()` method to your worker class, so you can terminate the thread gracefully in the close-event of the main-window:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.worker.stop()    
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
```

There is no need to implement `__del__` or call `deleteLater()` in your example. More generally, explict clean-up is usually only necessary for objects that are deleted during normal runtime (i.e. prior to program exit), so as to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the edit! What exactly would you put into `worker.stop()`? I could think of a call to `self.thread().requestInterruption()` maybe?

Comment: No - you cannot interrupt the thread, because it's blocked by the worker. You must directly interrupt the worker itself. For sequential processing with a loop, you can use a simple flag (e.g. `while self._running: ...`) which can be toggled by the stop method. However, if the task is CPU-bound and cannot be broken up into chunks, there will be literally *no way* to stop it, because python does not support true concurrency (due to the GIL). For cases like that, multithreading is the wrong approach and you must use multiprocessing instead.

Comment: PS: there's a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39999236/984421) that should make things clearer. It uses a mutex to protect the flag, but that's not strictly necessary if only one thread is reading/writing it - a bare attribute will work just a s well (as shown in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68938869/984421)).

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question to give an example application that motivated the reusable thread architecture and also iterate on @ekhumoro's answer. On the main thread you enqueue messages and start the other thread which processes these messages in the queue. You don't have to check if the thread is already running because `QThread.start()` is idempotent. You retain the variable of the same thread at all times not to induce garbage-collection crashes.
Periodically checking `QThread.isInterruptionRequested()` helps us terminate it gracefully.

```py
import sys, collections
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class LoggerWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Logger window")
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start thread")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        
        self.message_queue = collections.deque()
        
        self.worker = LoggerWindow.Worker(self.message_queue)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.process_messages)
        
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.enqueue_message)
    
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def enqueue_message(self, checked):
        self.message_queue.appendleft(len(self.message_queue) + 1)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def closeEvent(self, qCloseEvent):
        self.thread.requestInterruption()
        self.thread.quit()
        self.thread.wait()
        qCloseEvent.accept()
    
    class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
        def __init__(self, message_queue):
            super().__init__()
            self.message_queue = message_queue
            
        @QtCore.pyqtSlot()    
        def process_messages(self):
            while self.message_queue and not self.thread().isInterruptionRequested():
                self.thread().sleep(1)
                print(f"Processing message: {self.message_queue.pop()}/{len(self.message_queue)}")
            print("Finished processing!")
            self.thread().quit()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainGui = LoggerWindow()
    mainGui.show()
    app.exec()
```